# ParameterOverride failing on System.Type parameter

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm attempting to use a `ParameterOverride` with Unity 2.0.  It works fine as long as the parameter I'm supplying is not a System.Type.

In the following test program, I am injecting the constructor to `MyClass<T>` with an integer parameter when the generic parameter T is an int, and with a Type parameter when T is System.Type.  In the output that follows, you'll see that it handles the integer just fine, but seems to think that `typeof(MyClassForParam)` is an actual `MyClassForParam` object, not the type.  Any ideas?

```
namespace UnityParameterOverride
{
    interface IMyClass
    {
    }

    public class MyClass<T> : IMyClass
    {
        public MyClass(T myParam)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", myParam);
        }
    }

    public class MyClassForParam
    {
        public MyClassForParam() { }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IUnityContainer unity = new UnityContainer();
            try
            {
                // Works fine: prints 12345
                Console.WriteLine("Injecting an integer parameter.");
                unity.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass<int>>();
                unity.Resolve<IMyClass>(new ParameterOverride("myParam", 12345));

                // Fails: Seems to think that the parameter is an actual MyClassForParam instead of the type of that class.
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Injecting a Type parameter.");
                unity.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass<Type>>();
                unity.Resolve<IMyClass>(new ParameterOverride("myParam", typeof(MyClassForParam)));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output follows:

```
Injecting an integer parameter.
12345

Injecting a Type parameter. ----
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "UnityParameterOverride.IMyClass", name = "(none)".
```

Exception occurred while:

```
Exception occurred while: Resolving parameter "myParam" of constructor UnityParameterOverride.MyClass`1[[System.Type, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Type myParam).
Exception is: InvalidCastException - Unable to cast object of type 'UnityParameterOverride.MyClassForParam' to type 'System.Type'.
```

At the time of the exception, the container was:

```
Resolving UnityParameterOverride.MyClass1[System.Type],(none) (mapped from Un ityParameterOverride.IMyClass, (none)) Resolving parameter "myParam" of constructor UnityParameterOverride.MyClass1[ [System.Type, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c5 61934e089]](System.Type myParam)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unity gives special treatment to Type parameter definitions. See this post by Krzysztof Kozmic for more details: http://kozmic.pl/2008/12/03/unity-framework-and-the-principle-of-the-least-surprise/

Comment: **Perfect** answer!  In fact, Krzysztof Kozmic's example of injecting a Type argument into a ServiceHost is _exactly_ what I was doing IRL.

Comment: Just found this because I was having the same problem. trying to inject the ServiceType into a ServiceHost.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue after some spelunking in Unity I found that you can override the  default type resolution behavior by wrapping the naked type argument with an InjectionParameter:

```
new ParameterOverride("typeParameterArgument",new InjectionParameter(typeof(Type),typeof(MyNamespace.MyClassUsedAsInjectedTypeArgument)))
```

The constructor for ParameterOverride uses InjectionParameterValue.ToParameter() which will respect any predefined sub-class of InjectionParameterValue. This method should also work when using a PropertyOverride which uses the same method during construction.